How to convert non believers with ease
Without offending I'd like to sway another without having them totally shut me down I'm just looking for any suggestions

Converting someone to faith in God and the gospel is never easy! It always requires God's miraculous intervention in their life.

You shouldn't have to do anything with specific individuals. Be an ambassador. Set an example of what being a Christian is. Live a full Christian life that makes other people admire you and want to be like you.

We cannot even convert ourselves, because that is entirely the prerogative of God. We cannot convert another person for the same reason; that is entirely the prerogative of God. Salvation is all of God, his initiative, his conviction, his bringing to spiritual life. Not everyone professing Christian faith would agree with that, of course, but it is mainstream Reformed Protestant theology. You do not ask about that, so I won't go into it, but in one sense that makes the matter of conversion easier than if it were up to us!
Consider: if it was up to Christians to get non-Christians to convert to Christ, that would be an unbearable burden for us. We would be in agonies of despair at the millions we cannot reach with the gospel; we would be beating ourselves up continually regarding those we had shared the gospel with. ('Why did they walk away before I'd finished explaining? How can I put it more succinctly, more interestingly? Do they think I'm not sincere? Am I making it too complicated? Surely there's an easy way of converting others?' etc.)
With regard to the particular point in the question - is the idea of another person "shutting you down" really upsetting to you? Well, the New Testament has plenty of true-to-life examples of Christians being "shut down by others". Learn from them; for example, when Paul had explained the gospel of Christ to Festus, king Agrippa and his wife, in a very public setting. Here's what happened:

"As as he [Paul] thus spake for himself, Festus said with a loud
voice, Paul, thou art beside thyself; much learning doth make thee
mad... Then Agrippa said to Paul, Almost thou persuadest me to be a
Christian." Acts 26:24-32 A.V.

If Paul could (and he did) just keep going, taking every opportunity he got, then that is the example to follow. Sometimes it appeared that Paul had golden opportunities with great results, but very often people became angry at him and either beat him up, or got him thrown into prison (or both). Why should we hope to have an easy time of sharing the gospel with others?
The attitude to have is stated by Paul here:

"For the love of Christ constraineth us... Therefore if any man be in
Christ, he is a new creature: old things are passed away; behold, all
things are become new. And all things are of God, who hath reconciled
us to himself by Jesus Christ, and hath given to us the ministry of
reconciliation; to wit, that God was in Christ, reconciling the world
to himself, not imputing their trespasses unto them; and hath
committed unto us the word of reconciliation. Now then we are
ambassadors for Christ, as though God did beseech you by us; we pray
you in Christ's stead, be ye reconciled to God. For he hath made him
to be sin for us, who knew no sin; that we might be made the
righteousness of God in him." 2 Corinthians 5:14 & 17-21 A.V.

Ambassadors represent their King and country in a foreign land. That's how Christians are to be. In every aspect of life, we are to show the spirit of Christ so that whether speaking the gospel or silently living we point others to Christ. And, it goes without saying, we present the biblical gospel, not the easy-believism so popular today, where people are urged to "make a decision for Christ". That seems to make the conversions of others easy, but it results in no conversions whatever. The conversion of a sinner is a miracle of grace akin to the miracle of creation. Only God can do it, just as only God can create this universe and life in it. A spiritually dead person needs to be brought to spiritual newness of life. They are spiritually blind, but they need to hear to words of Christ, for "The entrance of your word brings light" (Psalm 119:130). By word and deed, keep pointing to Christ, the living Word, and the Holy Spirit - whose role is to lift Christ up - will bless that. Nobody ever said it would be easy! But you will get the Holy Spirit's enabling when all your concern is Christ, not yourself.
